# What language does Greedo speak?

Tags: star-wars, continuity

In the Clone Wars S03E04, Greedo speaks <strike>English</strike> Galactic Basic/Common. However, in "A New Hope", Greedo speaks... well, whatever he speaks, it's not English. What language is it, and also, does he manage to un-learn English in the next 20 years?

Comment: Fairly sure it's Huttese.

Comment: That would make sense! *facepalms* Thanks :)

Comment: Galactic basic or Common, not English

Comment: This proves that I haven't been doing my basic Star Wars research! :/

Comment: First time I ever saw it, I thought it was Italian.

Comment: Maybe I'm being racist or something, but could it be that the Rodian is speaking Rodese? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Languages_in_Star_Wars#Rodian_language

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Greedo is probably speaking *Huttese* in *A New Hope*. I say *probably* because there doesn't seem to be a canonical source that explicitly states the language in use.

Supporting, but not conclusive evidence for this:

- several of Greedo's lines appear on the "Speaking Huttese" page at [Wookieepedia](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Huttese)
- Wookieepedia also lists Huttese as one of the primary languages for Greedo's people, the Rodians. It cites the *Galactic Phrase and Travel Guide* for this information, which is a licensed work but not canon -- yet apparently explicitly states that Greedo's part of this conversation is Huttese.
- he is currently in employ of a Hutt (Jabba), who is never seen speaking anything else.
- other collaboratively-edited sites (such as IMDB) typically state it as Huttese in their quotes.

Detracting evidence:

- the [script](http://www.imsdb.com/scripts/Star-Wars-A-New-Hope.html) simply lists "a foreign tongue", but this is one of only a few occurrences of non-English dialogue.
- the novelisation makes out that they are both speaking the same language, or makes no mention of Greedo speaking something different.
- Rodians didn't even have a name until after the film came out. It first appeared in an RPG supplement. Like a lot of other things to do with Star Wars, people have built up much around it that isn't necessarily supported by the original sources.

Anyway... That he chose to speak this language to Han can not be taken as evidence that he didn't know *Galactic Basic* at this time -- he knew Han would be able to understand, and was able to understand Han's responses to him. Particularly the blaster bolt.

Huttese is the second most common language in the galaxy. Choosing to address Han in this language has no disadvantage.

In his appearance in the *Clone Wars* TV series he is talking to people who are somewhat more removed from the criminal spheres in which knowing Huttese is expected. Talking to Chairman Papanoida in Basic is necessary here.

Plus, there's really no need to make us read in a cartoon, is there?

Comment: How do you know he was speaking Huttese?

Comment: It's widely called that, wookiepedia says its a very common tongue, but the [script I can find](http://www.imsdb.com/Movie%20Scripts/Star%20Wars:%20A%20New%20Hope%20Script.html) only says "a foreign language".

Comment: Yes, I know that. So where did this "widely" known knowledge come from?

Comment: I assume you have the novelisation memorised. ;) does that give more to go on?

Comment: Nope. In the Star Wars novelisation, he's speaking English. From what I've read, the scene was originally filmed in English as well.

Comment: Example: http://www.imdb.com/character/ch0026868/quotes, several of his lines appear in the wookiepedia article for Huttese.

Comment: That's a wiki page. If I had more rep on IMDB I could change it to say that he was speaking Richardese.

Comment: I don't believe you'd have issues getting rep anywhere (if you cared to), but I've tried to expand on my answer to justify my opinion. :)

Comment: "Galactic Phrase and Travel Guide" is not a canon source of info

Comment: @Richard fair enough. is that based on the whitewash of all EU stuff, or some other reason?

Comment: Yes. All the supplementary materials are now non-canon, although I think most people would accept a word-of-god pronouncement on the subject from one of the film's writers/producers/directors/etc

Comment: @Richard can you teach me Richardese? Maybe I could get more scifi cred in that language, lol.

Comment: All kidding aside. I'm not sure how any of the Hutt references prove anything. The Hutt understand just about any language even though they speak their own. For example that little guy on his shoulder making screeching sounds, whatever language that is, Jabba understands it.

Comment: "...a Hutt, who are never seen speaking anything else." Except Ziro in The Clone Wars, but I guess he'd kinda the black sheep of the family.

Comment: @MichaelItzoe I must admit, I'm not a big follower of Clone Wars, so that didn't occur to me. :)

Comment: So Jabba understands everything but he needs a translator becuase he refuses to speak basic out of pride? That explains a lot!