# What changes have been made to the Disney+ versions of the Star Wars movies?

Tags: star-wars

The "Han Shot First" scene [has been changed again](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/223033/why-does-greedo-say-maclunkey-in-the-mos-eisley-cantina) in the version of *Star Wars* streaming on Disney+. Are there any other differences between the Disney+ versions of the Star Wars movies and the most recent Blu-ray release?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The biggest one is the Han/Greedo scene change done by Lucas himself before Disney acquired the rights but not released until now.

> Han Solo may have shot first in 1977’s original Star Wars, but now Greedo gets a verbal parting shot. Lucasfilm confirmed to Vanity Fair this was a change creator George Lucas made even before he sold Lucasfilm to Disney in 2012.
>
> <sub>[Vanity Fair, George Lucas Himself Gave Greedo the Last Word in Controversial New Star Wars Edit](https://www.vanityfair.com/hollywood/2019/11/greedo-han-solo-star-wars-edit)</sub>

> A representative for Lucasfilm confirmed in an email that the edits to the scene were made by Star Wars creator George Lucas himself before Disney acquired the company.
>
> <sub>[CNET, Greedo says 'Maclunkey' in Star Wars 'Han shot first' scene on Disney Plus](https://www.cnet.com/news/greedo-says-maclunkey-in-disney-plus-star-wars-han-shot-first-scene/)</sub>

The next biggest change is new scans made for the footage so they could release it in 4k, see the comparisons in [this tweet](https://twitter.com/cartycinema/status/1194286254327783424) for example.

[image: pre-4k shot of Luke] [image: post-4k shot of Luke]

[image: pre-4k shot of Han] [image: post-4k shot of Han]
<sub>*Click images to enlarge.*</sub>

Some minor details around the film which might be of interest:

- [The 20th Century Fox fanfare is back](https://twitter.com/JonLeeBrody/status/1194140307861848064).
- [There's a new Disney *Star Wars* intro piece](https://twitter.com/aaronfraggle/status/1194139333738946560).

As far as I can tell the only real editing changes are the Han/Greedo scene and the new 4k scans though. Nothing else has yet been found.